# Using confluent cp-schema-registry, does it have to talk to the same Kafka you are using for producers/consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We already have Kafka running in production. And unfortunately it's an older version, 0.10.2. I want to start using cp-schema-registry, from the community edition of Confluent Platform. That would mean installing the older 3.2.2 image of schema registry for compatibility with our old kafka.

From what I've read in the documentation, it seems that Confluent Schema Registry uses Kafka as it's backend for storing it's state. But the clients that are producing to/reading from Kafka topics talk to Schema Registry independently of Kafka.

So I am wondering if it would be easier to manage in production, running Schema Registry/Kafka/Zookeeper in one container all together, independent of our main Kafka cluster. Then I can use the latest version of everything. The other benefit is that standing up this new service component up could not cause any unexpected negative consequence to the existing Kafka cluster.

I find the documentation doesn't really explain well what the pros/cons of each deployment strategy are. Can someone offer guidance on how they have deployed schema registry in an environment with an existing Kafka? What is the main advantage of connecting schema registry to your main Kafka cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer Kafka clients are backwards compatible with Kafka 0.10, so there's no reason you couldn't use a newer Schema Registry than 3.2

In the docs

> *Schema Registry that is included in Confluent Platform 3.2 and later is compatible with any Kafka broker that is included in Confluent Platform 3.0 and later*

---

---

I would certainly avoid putting everything in one container... That's not how they're meant to be used and there's no reason you would need another Zookeeper server

Having a secondary Kafka cluster only to hold one topic of schemas seems unnecessary when you could store the same information on your existing cluster

> the clients that are producing to/reading from Kafka topics talk to Schema Registry independently of Kafka

Clients talk to both. Only Avro schemas are sent over HTTP before your regular client code reaches the topic. No, schemas and client data do not have to be part of the same Kafka cluster

Anytime anyone deploys Schema Registry, it's being added to "an existing Kafka", just the difference is yours might have more data in it

Comment: From this document https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html

This comment made me believe that there wasn't backward compatibility: 
> Each version of Confluent Platform includes several component services which are only compatible in that specific Confluent Platform version.

Comment: Scroll down to the schema registry - https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#cross-component-schema-registry